# Creating a template container for both copyable and non-copyable types

Tags: containers, c++17, move-semantics

I am trying to create a templated single producer/single consumer queue-like container that will support any C++ type (other than references).

I intend to have have two public methods, `enqueue` and `dequeue`, to support operations on the container, and my initial implementation of the container was as follows:

```
template<typename T, size_t N> class ring_queue {
public:
    bool enqueue(const T &v)
    {
        auto pos = end++;
        if (start % N == end % N) {
            --end;
            return false;
        }
        end %= N;
        std::optional<T> value(v);
        std::swap(storage[pos], value);
        return true;
    }

    bool dequeue(T &v)
    {
        size_t pos = start++;
        if (pos == end % N) {
            --start;
            return false;
        }
        std::optional<T> value;
        std::swap(storage[pos], value);
        v = std::move(value.value());
        start %= N;
        return true;
    }
private:
    std::array<std::optional<T>,N> storage;
    size_t start = 0;
    size_t end = 0;
};
```

As you can see, I'm using an `std::optional` here for the storage, the idea being that the only elements in the storage that contain values are those that are in the queue, so that if the queue is destroyed when it is empty (`start == end`), there will be no `T` destructors being called.

When `T` is a simple copy-able type such as `int`, or even `std::string` this works fine.

When `T` is an `std::unique_ptr`, for example, then things fall apart.  The idea with non-copyable types is that I want the container to own them while they are contained and then released when the element is dequeued.

How do I do this?

Comment: I never said I wanted them *both* in a single collection.  Any instance of ring_queue would contain only instances of one particular type.   I just want to modify ring_queue so that it works whether T is a copyable type or not.

Comment: My mistake. They have things in common but no shared heritage. Fine. So, why not treat them as the separate entities they are?

Comment: other than the convenience of only having one container instead of different ones, not much, I guess. Although it sort of defeats the point of using templates if I have to create different ones for different types.   Comments are of course welcome, but simply questioning why I would want to do this in the first place isn't helpful without at least presenting some objectively justifiable explanation for why I shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `enqueue` take a forwarding reference instead to forward whatever arguments the function gets to the constructor of `T`. You could skip the temporary `std::optional<T>` + `swap` too. Example:

```cpp
#include <utility>

// ...

    template<class... Args>
    bool enqueue(Args&&... v) {
        // ...
        storage[pos] = T{std::forward<Args>(v)...};
        // ...
    }
```

This would then work fine with non-copyables:

```
    ring_queue<std::unique_ptr<int>, 3> rq;
    rq.enqueue(std::make_unique<int>(1));
```

Comment: This kind of works.... although it changes the usage of the class so that if the element is non-copyable, then you have to pass the constructor arguments in instead of an instance.  I am not sure if that is the best I can hope for here.

Comment: @markt1964 The normal restrictions applies so if you already have an instance of the non-copyable, you need to `std::move` it. I can't think of another way. The good thing is that my suggested function handles move construction too.